# Proxy via pfSense and exclusions for DNS

Tags: network, firewalls, routing

## I have posted this to [NetworkEngineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/proxy-via-pfsense-and-exclusions-for-dns), as that seems the more suitable audience for this question.

I will leave this question open here but am happy to see it closed. I just did not want to delete it in case someone was working on a reply.

---

I am running pfSense 2.1 and having an issue with a Proxy.sh setup. In particular, I have pfSense configured to connect over OpenVPN to the Proxy.sh server `us-nj.proxy.sh` and to infinitely resolve the server.

It seems that the servers change from time-to-time, so pfSense has to re-resolve `us-nj.proxy.sh`. Unfortunately the system tries to connect to DNS (Google's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) through the now-disconnected proxy.

The server has interfaces `WAN` (being to my ISP, named **WAN_DHCP**) and `OPT1` (being to the Internet via the OpenVPN interface, named **ProxySHGW**)

I have configured the pfSense outbound NAT as follows:

```
Interface  Network   Protocol     WAN/OPT1     Ports 
WAN      any      tcp/udp/53     WAN     *       Straight DNS   
WAN      192.168.1.0/24  tcp/993     WAN     *       SMTP NAT   
WAN      192.168.1.0/24  tcp/*   tcp/465     WAN     *       SMTP/S NAT     
OPT1     192.168.1.128/25    *   OPT1    *       LAN to OPT1    
WAN      192.168.1.0/25      *   WAN     *       LAN to WAN     
WAN      127.0.0.0/8         *   WAN     1024:65535      localhost to WAN   
OPT1     127.0.0.0/8         *   OPT1    1024:65535      localhost to OPT1
```

As you can tell the network is split, with IP addresses `192.168.12.128 – 255` going to the OPT1/OpenVPN, and `192.168.1.0 – 127` to the WAN.

The firewall rules are as follows:

```
Proto Source  Port  Destination Port  Gateway
IPv4 *     *   *   8.8.8.8   *   WAN_DHCP
IPv4 *     *   *   8.8.4.4   *   WAN_DHCP 
IPv4 TCP   LAN net   *   *   465 (SMTP/S)  WAN_DHCP 
IPv4 TCP   LAN net   *   *   993 (IMAP/S)  WAN_DHCP 
IPv4 *   192.168.1.128/25  *   *   *   ProxySHGW
IPv4 *   192.168.1.0/25  *   *   *   WAN_DHCP
```

I would think that these firewall and NAT would cause DNS requests to route over the WAN, but in practice it does not.

Strangely enough though the SMTP/S and IMAP/s routing does work as expected.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here would be much appreciated.